# Understanding Identifiability problem of multiple smooths in GAMs/Additive models

Tags: generalized-additive-model, smoothing, identifiability

I am a beginner into additive models and GAMs, but have good enough knowledge of linear regression. I was going through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model#) wikipedia article to understand more, but can't seem to understand the identifiability problem for multiple smooths in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model#The_rank_reduced_framework) section. To Quote, Wikipedia says
[image]

This makes sense to me. However when I try to relate it to linear regression setting, i.e. If, for e.g., in case of linear regression, I have model equation as $Y=X\beta$, and if $X$ is full column rank, any $Y=X\gamma$ will mean $\gamma = \beta$, making the model identifiable.
If I am not wrong, I can write the equation for an additive model as $Y=\alpha+f(x)+f(v)$, or $Y=W\alpha$ where $W=[X  B  V]$ where $X$ is model matrix for parametric part of the model, and $B$, $V$ are basis functions for the smooths and $\alpha=[\beta \delta \gamma]$ (all transposed). In the later case, why isn't $W$ being full rank sufficient for smooths to be identifiable? **And why are smooths only identifiable to within an intercept term**?
I am sure I am missing something trivial, but haven't been able to zero in on it. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with smooths is that the basis expansion used to represent them in a model contains the constant function in the span of the basis. In effect, each smooth contains a constant term that is confounded with the intercept and any other smooths in the model. In that sense, if you have a model of the form

$$\hat{y}_i = \beta_0 + f_1(x_{1i}) + f_2(x_{2i})$$

then without any identifiability constraints the model would contain *three* constant terms, one per smooth plus one for the intercept.

With the default low-rank thin-plate regression spline in {mgcv}, the basis expansion literally contains a constant function (left panel below).

[image]

If you added any constant $c$ to the coefficient for that basis function and subtracted the same constant $c$ from the intercept, you'd have a different model (different coefficients) but the same fit and performance metrics.

The panel on the right (above) shows the basis after identifiability constraints have been applied, removing this constant basis function and effectively centring the smooth about the overall model constant (intercept) term.

Its less immediately clear that this problem affects other spline bases. For the cubic regression spline basis (left panel, below), there isn't a constant basis function in the basis, but such a function is in the span of functions representable by the basis (by adding a constant value $c$ to all the coefficients for the spline).

[image]

When the identifiability constraints are absorbed into the basis (right panel above) adding a constant $c$ to all the coefficients for the basis functions in the CRS basis doesn't result in a vertical shift of the entire spline and hence is no-longer confounded with the intercept.

If you want to think of this from a linear modelling perspective, it would be like modelling with three columns containing constant values (three columns of 1s say), which would make the model matrix $\mathbf{X}$ not be of full rank.